# Problems With Retrieving Values From a Dictionary

Tags: c#, parsing, data-retrieval, storing-data

I'm trying to make an interpreter for a toy language for learning more about how they work and so on, I'm now stuck on retrieving stored variables.

At first I used a dictionary where both the key and value is a `string` type. But after running in to the problem I made numerous attempts to solve it. I thought the `Dictionary` was the problem and made my own class, which didn't work any better so I'm back to the dictionary.

I have a text file called `"Test.txt"` where the code is written in and then read from by the lexer. The lexer makes tokens which then gets passed to the parser and so on.

```
    // '%' for declaring a variable
    //     that can be either a string and a number
    // Code form "Test.txt"

    %var = 100
    print %var

    //the assignment works fine, but the printing doesn't.
```

the lexer makes a `string` token out of the variable that looks like this: `VAR:%var` which I then send to the parser.

Then we have the `DoPRINT` method which will print a token that is given from the parser, *This isn't stable*. which I will work on after the variable retrieving works. Then we have the dictionary called `Symbols` with corresponding methods for adding and retrieving

```
        private void AssignVAR(String VarName, String VarValue)
        {
            Symbols[VarName] = VarValue;
        }

        private String GetVAR(String VarName)
        {
            if(Symbols.ContainsKey(VarName))
                return Symbols[VarName];
            else
                return "Undefined Variable: " + VarName;
        }

        private void DoPRINT(String ToPrint)
        {
            if(ToPrint.Substring(0, 6) == "STRING")
                // initially = 'STRING:"<text>"'
                Console.WriteLine(ToPrint.Substring(8, ToPrint.Length - 9));
            else if(ToPrint.Substring(0, 3) == "NUM")
                // initially = 'NUM:<number>'
                Console.WriteLine(ToPrint.Substring(4));
            else if(ToPrint.Substring(0, 4) == "EXPR")  
      // initially = 'EXPR:<expression>'       
      Console.WriteLine(Core.EvaluateEXPR(ToPrint.Substring(5)).ToString());
            else if(ToPrint.Substring(0, 3) == "VAR") 
                // initially = "VAR:%var"
                // when the "Symbols" are printed out
                // the name is "%var" which is the same
                // as the substring below
                Console.WriteLine(GetVAR(ToPrint.Substring(4)));
        }
```

I want the output to be what I assigned the variable to, `"100"` but when executing I only get `"Undefined Variable: %var"` even though if I print out the content of Symbols I get `%var` and if I print out what the `GetVAR()` function gets as input, it is also `%var` why is it then returning `"Undefined Variable: %var"`

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not in the code you have provided but in the code that calls it.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in `GetVAR` and examine the values in the debugger? Does the dictionary contain the key `%var` with value `100`? Also, we're assuming here that `print` calls `GetVAR`, right? Maybe you should also post that.

Comment: Also, you should really do some argument validation - your methods are making assumptions on the input that is not necessarily valid. `ToPrint.Substring(0, 6)` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `ToPrint.Length < 6`.

Comment: @RufusL i don't get an `ArgumentException` it just overrides the value that is allready assigned. Then to the `ToPrint.Substring(0, 6)` the length will never be less than 6 scince the lexer adds the token `STRING:"<text>"` so it just checks if it is a `STRING` token then prints it without the `STRING:` and the `"` quotes

Comment: And according to your comments, the lexer may also pass `"NUM:5"`, which would throw an exception on the first `if` condition.

Comment: @RufusL that is correct the `NUM:5` gives a crash, i will look into that and fix stuff like that. But i would really like to get the variables to work before i take on another task.

Comment: `the Dictionary didn't work` - what was the nature of the didn't workageness? ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  i guess i does work, but my program isn't functionally properly so i just blame it on the Dictionaries... PS i just have bad choices of words :)

Comment: It's always helpful if you describe the nature of your difficulty as accurately as possible (including the actual error message(s), if any).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the problem is as said, retrieving the variable value form the `VarMemmory` class and there are no errors, if not counting what `RufusL` said about the `NUM:5` error. And i am trying my best to explain it without making the post look like an article.

Comment: There's obviously a small mistake somewhere. Dump out the `VarNames` array right before you return "Undefined Variable".

Comment: @500-InternalServerError if you mean writing out the content, it is `[%var, NUM:100]` and that's whats had me going crazy for about 1.5 weeks right now. i allso give the error the `Varname` so it prints `"Undefined Variable: %var"`

Comment: No, I meant something like `foreach (var vn in VarNames) Console.WriteLine($">{vn}<");` - that should let you see what you're comparing against and hence why it fails. (this is off the top of my head, so caveat emptor).

Comment: It looks like one problem is that when you update the value of an existing variable, you're adding a *new entry* into both lists, but when you go to look up the value of a variable, you grab the first one instead of the last one, so you're getting the original value. Please explain what's wrong with using a dictionary - it's built to store key/value pairs, like a variable name and value. (also, I've deleted my obsolete comments, you might want to do the same to clean up this section)

Comment: @RufusL after days of not getting anywhere whith solving it, i thought the Dictionary was the problem. i will re-implement the dictionary and update the post as soon as possible. And yes i can now see the problem with the multiple entries now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that assigning using a method and the retrieving also using a method does something that sort of corrupts the accessible variable.

Changing so that the variable assignment happens in the main function of the parser rather than using a method for it worked fine, and getting the value with a function works perfectly.
No idea if this has to do with movement of the data while the function is being executed. But it works, but i can't seem to figure out why.